# Laravel 5.6: Prevent input field repopulating after validation error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am using Laravel 5.6 with the [HTML collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html) to build a form. I have a request class that handles the form validation and when validation fails the form inputs get repopulated with the value that was submitted. I would like to prevent this from happening on the google2fa field though so that it is always blank and doesn't get repopulated. Is there a way to do this?

**Controller:**

```
public function login()
{
    return View::make('auth/login');
}

public function handle_login(UserLoginRequest $request)
{
    // login successful
}
```

**Request**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Validator;
use App\Models\User;
use Auth;
use Guzzle;
use Hash;
use Google2FA;

class UserLoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // check email and password combination is valid
        Validator::extend('valid_login', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
        {
            $user = User::where('email', '=', $value)->first();
            if($user) {
                return Hash::check($parameters[0], $user->password);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            return Auth::attempt(['email' => $value, 'password' => $parameters[0]], !is_null($parameters[1]));
        });

        // check recaptcha 
        Validator::extend('notBot', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
        {
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
            try {
                $response = $client->post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', [
                    'form_params' => [
                        'secret' => config('services.recaptcha.secret'),
                        'response' => $value,
                        'remoteip' => $this->ip()
                    ]
                ]);
                $result = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

                if($result->success) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    $this->recaptcha_errors = implode(', ', $result->{'error-codes'});
                    return false;
                }
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        // check the two factor authentication
        Validator::extend('2fa_valid', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
        {
            $user = User::where('email', '=', $this->email)->first();

            if(is_null($user)) {
                return true;
            }

            return Google2FA::verifyKey($user->google2fa_secret, $value);
        });

        Validator::replacer('notBot', function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
            return str_replace(':errors', $this->recaptcha_errors, $message);
        });

        return [
            //'g-recaptcha-response' => ['bail', 'required', 'notBot'],
            'email' => ['bail', 'required', 'exists:users,email', 'valid_login:'.$this->password.','.$this->remember_me],
            'password' => ['required'],
            'google2fa' => ['required', '2fa_valid']
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'email.valid_login' => 'The password is incorrect.',
            'email.is_user' => 'The email address is not recognised.',
            'not_bot' => 'Recaptcha error: :errors',
            'g-recaptcha-response.required' => 'You must prove you are not a robot',
            'google2fa.2fa_valid' => 'The 2 factor auth code is invalid',
            'google2fa.required' => 'You must enter a 2 factor auth code'
        ];
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('meta_title')
    Login
@stop

@section('content')

    {{ Form::open(['route' => 'login.submit', 'id' => 'user-login', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'method' => 'POST']) }}
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>Please Login</h2>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group has-danger">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="email">E-Mail Address</label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        {{ Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'email', 'required', 'autofocus', 'placeholder' => 'Email address...' ]) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        {{ Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'password', 'required', 'placeholder' => 'Password...']) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="password">2 Factor Auth Code</label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        {{ Form::text('google2fa', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'required', 'placeholder' => '2 Factor Auth Code...']) }}
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm rounded-circle" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="bottom" title="What is 2 factor authentication?" data-content="2 factor authentication is an extra layer of security to protect your account from unauthorised access. <br><br><a href='{{ route('login.setup_2fa') }}' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'>Setup 2 Factor Authentication</a>"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></button></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{--
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeZAFgUAAAAAKYQAqxk5Vt2TiaR9ryk7VsIA_0F"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        --}}
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-top: .35rem">
                <div class="form-check mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        {{ Form::checkbox('remember', 1, false, ['class' => 'form-check-input']) }}
                        <span style="padding-bottom: .15rem">Remember me</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center" style="padding-top: 1rem">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login</button>
                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('login.forgotten_password') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{ Form::close() }}

@stop

@section('scripts')
    {{-- <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script> --}}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                html: true
            })
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use '**autocomplete="off"**' on that input, you can read more about this attribute [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

```
{{ Form::text('google2fa', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'required', 'placeholder' => '2 Factor Auth Code...', 'autocomplete' => 'off']) }}
```

Comment: That's not quite what I meant. It's not the browser remembering the previous entries its HTML collective repopulating the field with the value that was submitted

Comment: Updated my answer for correct syntax,  but you set default value to '' so it's not collective thats populating your field, therefore why I suggested adding autocomplete=off as an attribute

Comment: What I mean is that if you set Form::text default value to nothing then it is the browser the one who is remembering previous entries, you sure this doesn't fix it?

Comment: Yeah that's the default for if the form hasn't been submitted. If the form is submitted and validation fails though then the default becomes whatever value was submitted.

Comment: With autocomplete='off' still behaves like that?

Comment: Yep. As I said autocomplete off is a html attribute to instruct the browser not to remember previous entries and suggest them to the user. The problem here is that the default behaviour of the HTML collective is to repopulate all the form fields with the submitted values so that if you make a mistake you don't have to fill everything in again from scratch. I'd like to prevent it doing that on one field

Comment: Well if you really tried and it doesn't work I'd create an issue on their github since I don't see this documented anywhere